# How to make a group of selected elements selectable to respond independently the droppable hover depending on the area beneath?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I got 3 areas, which are one next to the other, and the ability to multi-select blocks inside any of these 3 areas, but the problem is that when i start dragging those 3 selected blocks that are inside of any of the areas, only the one that i got the cursor on is affected by the droppable hoverClass.

Is there any way to get the area beneath every single multi-dragged block independently instead of the cursor one during drag event?

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5nbjqojn/5/).

I would like to get the block area that is being hovered over during drag.

The only thing i get is the Source, not the destination one.

```
$(".block").draggable({
    drag: function(event, ui) {
        console.log($(ui.helper).closest(".global-region").attr("id"));
    }
});
```

Comment: ..you mean something like `GetAreaAtPoint(event.ClientX, event.ClientY)` or something to that effect?

Comment: when you add console.log .. you should add the event object `console.log("ID:" + $(ui.helper).closest(".global-region").attr("id") + " - [Object] %O [EVENT] %O", $(ui.helper).closest(".global-region"), event)`

Comment: Yes Bret, something like that... something that tells me what area is that block over. Using only draggable drag event (not droppable)

Comment: well the clientX and clientY do change on the event. though I suspect they are probably associated to the element you're dragging.. not your mouse.. calculations are probably in order... it may be easier to maintain the `Regions` (aka Area) dimensions in a seperate json object.. I'll mock something up for you here in a bit

Comment: Yea i thought that the only way is by doing it from the dragged objects coordinates based on the coordinates of the areas :C

Comment: opps.. I forgot all about this question, sorry.. I thought maybe someone would have provided something on it by now actually... As a side note, you should take a look at Pixi.js and how they establish Regions and Points.. pixi.js is essentially an api ontop of the WebGL api, but that's really above the scope of what I'm recommending you to review..